# ANDROID create a clickable ListView

Tags: android, listview

> So in a nutshell I would like clicking on an item in the list to open a page with more data for that item.
>   I know that maybe I'm asking too much, but I need your help.

Hello everyone, I want to create me for personal application that I can remember over the years all the problems of geometry that I made, so I did a database, and I made an adapter to put the items in a table with the same layout: https://gyazo.com/f907281860906d6301bd98d896351650
(in this table you see only the name of the figure and a personal note), but the fact is that when I put the data in the form 
https://gyazo.com/b14e0877e23612ac6d77bf328305651f
I put them over the name of the figure and the personal note also insert data so that when you view in that table I click on the "Open" button can not see the data of the problem, is there any way to do this? Here you will be given the DBHelper, the layout of the elements, the ListDataAdapter and MainAcivity of 'activity that has to read these boxes.

DBHelper

```
package com.example.gioele.mathup;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Gioele on 13/07/2015.
 */
public class LocalDB1Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//--------------inizializzazione/creazione database------------------------------------------------------------
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "linguaggiodb";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSIONS = 4;
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
    "CREATE TABLE "+ LocalDB2.tabella1.TABLE_NAME+" (" + LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_LINGUAGGIO + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_FIGURA1 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_FIGURA2 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_NICKNAME_PROBLEM + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_1 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_2 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_3 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_4 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_5 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_6 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_7 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_8 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_9 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_10 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_11 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_12 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_13 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_14 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_15 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_16 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_17 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_18 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_19 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_20 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_21 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_22 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R1 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R2 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R3 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R4 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R5 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R6 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R7 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R8 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R9 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R10 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R11 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R12 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R13 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R14 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R15 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R16 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R17 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R18 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R19 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R20 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R21 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.R22 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR1 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR2 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR3 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR4 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR5 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR6 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR7 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR8 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR9 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR10 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR11 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR12 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR13 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR14 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR15 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR16 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR17 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR18 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR19 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR20 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR21 + " TEXT,"+
            LocalDB2.tabella1.RR22 + " TEXT );";
            ;





    public LocalDB1Helper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSIONS);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS","Database create / opened.....");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Table created");

    }
//------------comandi: leggi, scrivi----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //scrivi
    public void addInformations(String linguaggio,
                                String user_figura1,
                                String user_figura2,
                                String user_nickname_problem,
                                String scritta1,
                                String scritta2,
                                String scritta3,
                                String scritta4,
                                String scritta5,
                                String scritta6,
                                String scritta7,
                                String scritta8,
                                String scritta9,
                                String scritta10,
                                String scritta11,
                                String scritta12,
                                String scritta13,
                                String scritta14,
                                String scritta15,
                                String scritta16,
                                String scritta17,
                                String scritta18,
                                String scritta19,
                                String scritta20,
                                String scritta21,
                                String scritta22,

                                String r_1,
                                String r_2,
                                String r_3,
                                String r_4,
                                String r_5,
                                String r_6,
                                String r_7,
                                String r_8,
                                String r_9,
                                String r_10,
                                String r_11,
                                String r_12,
                                String r_13,
                                String r_14,
                                String r_15,
                                String r_16,
                                String r_17,
                                String r_18,
                                String r_19,
                                String r_20,
                                String r_21,
                                String r_22,

                                String rr_1,
                                String rr_2,
                                String rr_3,
                                String rr_4,
                                String rr_5,
                                String rr_6,
                                String rr_7,
                                String rr_8,
                                String rr_9,
                                String rr_10,
                                String rr_11,
                                String rr_12,
                                String rr_13,
                                String rr_14,
                                String rr_15,
                                String rr_16,
                                String rr_17,
                                String rr_18,
                                String rr_19,
                                String rr_20,
                                String rr_21,
                                String rr_22,


                                SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_LINGUAGGIO,linguaggio);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_FIGURA1,user_figura1);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_FIGURA2,user_figura2);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_NICKNAME_PROBLEM,user_nickname_problem);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_1,scritta1);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_2,scritta2);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_3,scritta3);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_4,scritta4);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_5,scritta5);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_6,scritta6);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_7,scritta7);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_8,scritta8);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_9,scritta9);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_10,scritta10);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_11,scritta11);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_12,scritta12);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_13,scritta13);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_14,scritta14);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_15,scritta15);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_16,scritta16);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_17,scritta17);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_18,scritta18);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_19,scritta19);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_20,scritta20);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_21,scritta21);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_22,scritta22);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R1,r_1);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R2,r_2);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R3,r_3);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R4,r_4);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R5,r_5);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R6,r_6);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R7,r_7);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R8,r_8);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R9,r_9);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R10,r_12);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R11,r_12);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R12,r_12);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R13,r_12);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R14,r_12);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R15,r_15);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R16,r_16);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R17,r_17);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R18,r_18);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R19,r_19);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R20,r_20);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R21,r_21);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.R22,r_22);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR1,rr_1);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR2,rr_2);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR3,rr_3);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR4,rr_4);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR5,rr_5);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR6,rr_6);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR7,rr_7);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR8,rr_8);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR9,rr_9);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR10,rr_10);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR11,rr_11);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR12,rr_12);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR13,rr_13);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR14,rr_14);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR15,rr_15);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR16,rr_16);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR17,rr_17);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR18,rr_18);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR19,rr_19);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR20,rr_20);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR21,rr_21);
        contentValues.put(LocalDB2.tabella1.RR22,rr_22);


        db.insert(LocalDB2.tabella1.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "One row inserted");

    }
    //leggi
    public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "AVVIATO");
        Cursor cursor;
        final String[] uno = {LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_LINGUAGGIO,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_FIGURA1,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_FIGURA2,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.USER_NICKNAME_PROBLEM,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_1,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_2,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_3,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_4,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_5,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_6,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_7,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_8,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_9,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_10,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_11,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_12,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_13,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_14,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_15,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_16,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_17,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_18,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_19,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_20,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_21,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.SCRITTA_22,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R1,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R2,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R3,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R4,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R5,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R6,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R7,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R8,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R9,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R10,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R11,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R12,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R13,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R14,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R15,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R16,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R17,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R18,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R19,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R20,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R21,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.R22,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR1,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR2,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR3,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR4,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR5,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR6,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR7,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR8,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR9,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR10,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR11,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR12,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR13,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR14,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR15,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR16,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR17,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR18,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR19,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR20,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR21,
                LocalDB2.tabella1.RR22,
                };

        Cursor c = db.query(LocalDB1.tabella1.TABLE_NAME, uno, null, null, null, null, null);
        return c;

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


}
```

ListDataAdapter

```
package com.example.gioele.mathup;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Gioele on 24/09/2015.
 */
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList<>();
    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }


    static class LayoutHandler
    {
        TextView user_figura1, user_figura2, user_nickname_problem;
    }
    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View tabella2 = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if(tabella2 == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            tabella2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tabella2,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.user_figura1 = (TextView)tabella2.findViewById(R.id.figura11);
            layoutHandler.user_figura2 = (TextView)tabella2.findViewById(R.id.figura22);
            layoutHandler.user_nickname_problem = (TextView)tabella2.findViewById(R.id.nominativo);
            tabella2.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else{
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) tabella2.getTag();

        }

        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.user_figura1.setText(dataProvider.getUser_figura1());
        layoutHandler.user_figura2.setText(dataProvider.getUser_figura2());
        layoutHandler.user_nickname_problem.setText(dataProvider.getUser_nickname_problem());
        return tabella2;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
final ListView listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.tabella2);
            listview1.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
            helper = new LocalDB1Helper(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            c2 = helper.getInformations(SQLiteDatabase);
            if (c2.moveToFirst()) {
                do{
                    String user_figura1, user_figura2, user_nickname_problem;
                    user_figura1 = c2.getString(1);
                    user_figura2 = c2.getString(2);
                    user_nickname_problem = c2.getString(3);
                    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(user_figura1, user_figura2, user_nickname_problem);
                    listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

                }while (c2.moveToNext());
            }
```

So in a nutshell I would like clicking on an item in the list to open a page with more data for that item.
I know that maybe I'm asking too much, but I need your help.

Comment: Ah in my language: linguaggio = language, figura = figure, scritta = text and r1-22 and rr1-22 are the data of geometric problem

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` method. You provide an [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) here, which's onItemClick method gets called when the user clicks an item of the list view.